# HTML Form submit button won't go to php

Tags: html, forms, button

First of all i would like to say that i'm a real newbie, learing HTML, CSS and PHP by this website and trail&error.

My problem is as following:

My HTML button won't submit the form to my PHP. I can't really see what im doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

My code is:

```
<div class="contact-inner">
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="emailcontact.php">
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="naam" class="form-control wow bounceInLeft" placeholder="Uw naam">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control wow bounceInLeft" placeholder="Uw emailadres">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 ">
<textarea name="bericht" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Uw bericht"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="btn-container col-md-12 text-center submit">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Verstuur!</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I hope it not a too stupid mistake.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Gr. Tom

Comment: How have you validated that it does not post to emailcontact.php?

Comment: Also, does the emailcontact.php exist in the same folder level? (Does the post method generate a 404)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your syntax; well apart from an unclosed `contact-inner` div, but that will not affect the form submission process. I reckon you're running into `404` error or some javascript is preventing the submit process

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following to try out if your html's problem or PHP's

1. If you got an 404 error, you may be writing a wrong location for emailcontact.php
2. Add following code to the top of emailcontact.php:

```php
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

If you got var_dump the same data as what you've post, it means you program actually works.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Verstuur!</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">Verstuur!</input>
```

Comment: Technically, this shouldn't cause a problem. A `<button>` will submit a form too

Comment: If a `button`'s `type` is `"button"`, it acts like you describe. But with `type="submit"` (the default) it acts like a submit input: http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#attr-button-type

Comment: anything to do with the browser specific implementation?

Comment: @premkumar tell me a browser that the fiddle above doesn't work in

Comment: @Gareth i m trying to understand the problem. i suggested this solution because i have used input style submit. If both are equivalent(they are equivalent) I would like to know why it did not work for one who posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

add an id to your form ( for example "myform" )
then in your button code :

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="document.getElementById("myform").submit()">Verstuur!</button>
```

Comment: Overkill, do not fix what is not broken.

Comment: @asprin what is the difference between that fiddle and his code ?